# JPA join in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, join

I've read examples but have my personal question to you.
I have 2 tables:

`Role:
  id, name
User:
  id, login, name, role_id`

#### Role entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 45)
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "role")
private Set<User> user = new HashSet<>();

//getters and setters
```

#### User entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Role role;

//getters and setters
```

#### And repository:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

String Q_GET_ALL_USERS = "from User u left join Role r on u.role_id=r.id";

@Query(Q_GET_ALL_USERS)
Collection<User> getAllUsers();
```

This code is showing: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from com.example.jpa.model.User u left join Role r on u.role_id=r.id]`

How I understand entity can't contains 'id' (in my case in `Role`) for references and I should remove this field. But entity should have '@Id'.

In this case I should create new column in 'Role'? or I can use more beautiful decision?

I put all project to [bb](https://bitbucket.org/qizer/sample)

Comment: you've forgotten the "SELECT u" from the start of your JPQL.

Comment: Yes, i forgot `select u`

Answer (score 8):

To use join in HQL (JPQL) you don't need `on` clause

```
String Q_GET_ALL_USERS = "select u from User u left join u.role";
```

This query doesn't have any sence because of you don't use `role` in the where clause.

If you want to get users with a fetched role you can use `join fetch`

```
String Q_GET_ALL_USERS = "select u from User u left join fetch u.role";
```

**Update**

Your schema for `User` and `Role` is not commonly used. I advice to you make `@ManyToMany` association from user to roles and remove any `user` association from the `Role`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Role> roles;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    private String name;

}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for response.
In my situation both queries is correct, but your answers provided me useful information.

Comment: Also i have question about 'role' entity. I've read that `@OneToMany` must be a collection (Set). Can I do any changes in code and instead `Set<User> user` use `User user` (without collection)?

Comment: @qizer No. You need a collection for the `@OneToMany` association — `Set` or `List`. I update my answer.

Comment: @v.ladynev  +1 for the advise to use `@ManyToMany` association. But why the `Role` in `User` class is not a `List` or `Set` ?

Comment: @v.ladynev good advise, but with your advise I receive: `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.example.jpa.model.User.role`. If I set collection `private Set<Role> role` i see `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER_ROLE`

Comment: @qizer I am so sorry, I forget about to change property to `Set<Role> roles`. Update my answer. And I think, you need to recreate or update  your database schema. `USER_ROLE` is a join table for the `@MainToMain` association.

Comment: @OmkarPuttagunta Thank you, I forget about it.

Comment: @v.ladynev now i getting it: `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER_ROLE`.
Found: problem was that hibernate thying join to this table. Added `@JoinTable(name = "role")` and received: `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_nvt31tls2ym5so7gx2s6gopi0:role [role_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (role [user_id,role_id])`

Comment: @qizer `USER_ROLE` is a join table for the @MainToMain association. You need to let Hibernate create it. Run program with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` to delete all tables  and create it again.

Comment: @v.ladynev I understand what will be... 3 tables, in third table will be user id and role and select should be from `user_role`? Because old query select rows without `role`

Comment: @qizer No. Hibernate uses the `user_role` table internally, when you do `User u left join u.role`,  Hibernate ads two joins in the SQL, so you don't need to specify the `user_role` table (and you can't do it — you can't refer to the `user_role` in the JPQL)

Comment: @v.ladynev something was missed... with such describing the hibernate is create table `user` with foreign key on `id` and column `role_id` is missing in the table. And after that table `user_role` is empty. I added `@Column(name = "role_id")`. But I should say hibernate that column 'role_id' from `user_role` must be from column `user.role_id`, not `user.id`

Comment: @qizer _column role_id is missing in the table_ — it is correct, `User` doesn't need the column `role_id`.  _'role_id' from `user_role` must be from column `user.role_id`, not `user.id`_ — It is not correct `user_role.role_id` must be a foreign key to the `Role`. Try to use `@JoinTable` annotation may be it helps you to understand. See [this](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-examples/simply-console/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/example/mysql/persistent/User.java#L86) as an example. It is associate `User` to himself.

Comment: @v.ladynev thank you for your patience :-) . Last question (I hope). On app initialization step hibernate create only structure. Data (for 3 tables shoul be iitialized manually (insert for 3x tables)). In realtime i can create object `User` and save it and this transaction will add information to `user` and `user_role` tables. Please correct me. I will add answer without `@ManyToMany` annotation, because method with this annotation must be investigated by me :-)

Comment: @qizer You are correct. You need to create roles in the database, add those roles to the `User` and save the `User`, Hibernate fill the`user_role` table properly.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should create a new column in `User`.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;
```

Comment: Just a note, If we use `@OneToMany` with `mappedBy` Hibernate uses `@JoinColumn` by default.

Comment: @qizer It's a reminder that you should accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for answers. Right entities and query below (plus tables schema).

Tables (queries)

```
CREATE TABLE role (
  id   INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user (
  id        INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  login     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  user_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  role_id   INT         NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES role (id)
);
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Role role;

//getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 45)
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "role")
private Set<User> user = new HashSet<>();

//getters and setters
}
```

Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

String Q_GET_ALL_USERS = "select u from User u left join u.role";

@Query(Q_GET_ALL_USERS)
Collection<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

[@v-ladynev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3405171/v-ladynev) proposed alternative decision(use only `@ManyToMany` in `User`). More details you can find in comments under this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35149405/1137763). 
When I check this decision I will update this answer (I hope I don't forget it :-))

Answer (score 0):

> **Models**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_std_user")
public class StdUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "class_id")
    public int classId;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    public String userName;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_std_profile")
public class StdProfile {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "pro_id")
    public int proId;
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    public String fullName;
}
```

> **Controllers**

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@GetMapping("/join")
    public List actionJoinTable() {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List arr_cust = em
                .createQuery("SELECT u.classId, u.userName, p.fullName FROM StdUser u, StdProfile p WHERE u.classId=p.proId")
                .getResultList();
        return arr_cust;
    }
```

> **Result:**

```
[
    [
        1,
        "Ram",
        "Ram Pukar Chaudhary"
    ],
    [
        2,
        "Raja",
        "Raja Kishor Shah"
    ]
]
```

Comment: i wouldn't recommend this approach, plus, it is not using joins.